# Old classes code still shown on Android Developer Console

Tags: android

I made some fixes for some issues and updated my APK in Google developer console. I noticed some exceptions are shown with the new application version, but with old line number from the previous application version. 
My question: Is this a transient issue? the old class will be replaced once the update is completed. If this is the case, is there anything I can do to prevent the execution of code from both versions at the same time?